# Counting Sort C++11

Tags: c++11

Here is an implementation of counting sort in c++11. It does not give any output. What possibly went wrong? Should not the std::copy copies back the sorted array to the original array?

```
void counting_sort::sort_array(int array[], int n)
{
std::vector <int> a;
a.insert(a.end(), &array[0], &array[n]);
std::vector <int> b;

auto k = *std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end());
auto m = *std::min_element(a.begin(), a.end());

auto x = k - m + 1;
std::vector<int>v(x);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        v[a[i]-m]++;

    for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
        v[i]=v[i]+v[i-1];

    for(int i = a.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        { 
        b[v[a[i]-m]-1] = a[i]; 
        v[a[i]-m]--; 
    }

std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), array);
```

}

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. `b` is an empty vector, `b[i]` is invalid for any value of `i`

Comment: How do you suggest to fix it? I have another version using only arrays with segmentation fault here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842681/segmentation-fault-chkstk-ms-c. Thanks.

Comment: You fix it by resizing the vector to a necessary size. You know how to do it - you've done it with `v`.

Comment: I tried that. It still does not give any output.

Comment: Following Igor's advice results in no output, but not a crash. You are now in a good position to step through the algorithm with a debugger and see where it deviates from the expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? What output do you expect? Your code doesn't contain any library calls that may result in output being produced.

Comment: Yes, it is void. But it should modify the array so that it is sorted. The output is produced by the main function which is not here. I found out that the problem is with x value that can be very big. Consider if k = 2 billion and m = -2 billion, then x = 4 billion. What should I use to make sure it works with this range?

Comment: Counting sort is not suitable in this case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort : *"counting sort is an algorithm for sorting a collection of objects according to keys that are **small integers**"* (emphasis mine)